# string to date conversion in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string "13/6/2011".I have to convert it into DateTime. For this i am using

```
 DateTime.ParseExact("13/6/2011","DD/MM/YYYY",null);
```

But it showing

```
 String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

exception.
Any idea why?

Comment: Your date is of length 9 but you format is of length 10.

Comment: 1. As said Ash - MM is two symbols, but you provide 1. 2. DD must be dd (lower letters)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to the "6" vs "06" problem that ChrisF has mentioned, your format string is incorrect. Day-of-month is "dd" and year is "yyyy", so you should have a format of "dd/MM/yyyy".

Additionally, I'd recommend explicitly passing in `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, as otherwise the "/" could *actually* be treated as a different (culture-specific) date separator. (Another alternative is to quote the slashes, but I think using an invariant culture pins things down more.)

In other words, I'd use something like this:

```
// Sample for text: 13/06/2011
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you *don't* necessarily have a two-digit day or month, use:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "d/M/yyyy",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It's not immediately clear to me whether that *also* copes with (say) 13/06/2011 though.

Answer (score 5):

Your month format is `MM` but you've only specified a single digit for the month.

If you enter `06` it should work, or if you use the `M` format specifier for the month this will take a single digit.

Also (as Jon Skeet has mentioned) you've used `DD` and `YYYY` instead of `dd` (or `d` to cope with single digit days) and `yyyy`.

For a full list of the various date-time format specifiers, see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a different format string:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("13/6/2011","dd/MM/yyyy",null);
```

Or you could just use `d` which is for 'short date format' [as defined on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

```
DateTime.ParseExact("13/6/2011","d",null);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt=  DateTime.ParseExact("13/06/2011","dd/MM/yyyy",null);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("13/6/2011","DD/M/YYYY",null);
```

Comment: Do know the difference between `DD` and `dd`? or `YYYY` and `yyyy` at least?

Comment: you right I just draw attention on month format token but miss that day and year are incorrect